# Google oauth2 refresh token generation limit for single project

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

Can someone please help me find the official confirmation regarding what the refresh token generation limit for single project is regardless of how many users authorize access to it? Or if there is any limit at all?

I have gone through the google documentation and also read through answers provided here for similar questions asked earlier but cannot find any answer that pinpoints to the exact documentation that confirms this.

Google Api documentation:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration

Paragraph in context from google documentation:

> "There is currently a limit of 25 refresh tokens per user account per client. If the limit is reached, creating a new token automatically invalidates the oldest token without warning. This limit does not apply to service accounts.
>   There is also a larger limit on the total number of tokens a user account or service account can have across all clients. Most normal users won't exceed this limit but a developer's test account might."

It is clear from the documentation that 25 is the limit for client-user combination. However it is still not clear what the limit for a single project is. (or if there is a limit at all?)

p.s. The project I'm working would ask user to authorize then prompt him to allow offline access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no per project limit.